# Writing regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am weak in writing regular expressions so I'm going to need some help on the one. I need a regular expression that match to `section 7.01` and then `(a)`

Basically with `section` can be followed by any number like `6.1`/`7.1`/`2.1`

Examples:

```
SECTION 7.01. Events of Default. If any of the following events
("Events of Default") shall occur:
          (a) any Borrower shall fail to pay any principal of any Loan when and
     as the same shall become due and payable, whether at the due date thereof
     or at a date fixed for prepayment thereof or otherwise;
```

I am trying to write an regular expression which can give me groups which contains these

Group 1

```
SECTION 7.01. Events of Default. If any of the following events
("Events of Default") shall occur:
```

Group 2

```
(a) any Borrower shall fail to pay any principal of any Loan when and
     as the same shall become due and payable, whether at the due date thereof
     or at a date fixed for prepayment thereof or otherwise;
```

Also there can be more points after `(a)` like `b` and so on.

Please help me out in writing an regular expression.

Comment: Can we see what you've tried?

Comment: ^(?!\().* i was trying to include everything from section till (a) but instead it is skipping ("Events of Default") and including (a)

Comment: i wrote this also -> ^\s*<backslash>(([a-z]|a[a-z]|i[ivx]{0,2}|v[ivx]{0,2}|x[ivx]{0,2})<backslash>) but this is also not giving what i want.

Comment: Hmm, unless you strip away any newlines, and capture as a single string, I would recommend context sensitive parsing that tracks what nested level you are at.

Comment: Its fine, i can strip the newlines but isn't we can give `re.M` flag in regex to enable multi-line parsing?

Comment: There are a number of good online regex testers that are Python regex fluent.  Have you tried any? They are usually the first place I go to construct a pattern.

Comment: Are there any ```SECTION```'s not followed by a number and do not want matched?

Comment: No, all the sections are followed by number and i am trying `http://pythex.org/` to construct a pattern but i am blocked by my limited knowledge of regex.

Comment: Took me a lot of practice till I got comfortable, I spent a lot of time here - http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.  If I remember correctly it uses a different flavor than Python but it was good help with the basics - I ha to keep cross referencing with the Python re docs and that helped too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach, however, multiple **assumptions** are made. The section headers must begin with `SECTION` and end with a colon `:`. Secondly the sub-sections must begin with *matching* parenthesis', and end with a semi-colon.

```
import re
def extract_groups(s):
    sanitized_string = ''.join(line.strip() for line in s.split('\n'))
    sections = re.findall(r'SECTION.*?:', sanitized_string)
    sub_sections = re.findall(r'\([a-z]\).*?;', sanitized_string)
    return sections, sub_sections
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> s = """SECTION 7.01. Events of Default. If any of the following events
("Events of Default") shall occur:
          (a) Whether at the due date thereof
     or at a date fixed for prepayment thereof or otherwise;

          (b) Test;
SECTION 7.02. Second section:"""
>>> print extract_groups(s)
(['SECTION 7.01. Events of Default. If any of the following events("Events of Default") shall occur:', 'SECTION 7.02. Second section:'], 
['(a) Whether at the due date thereofor at a date fixed for prepayment thereof or otherwise;', '(b) Test;'])
```

Comment: How to modify the sub_section regex if it ends with `or` keyword instead of `;` for some?

Comment: Interesting, this complicates the requirements somewhat, what if there are `or`'s inside of the sub-sections that end with `;`. With the flattened string that we use here, it is difficult to derive the context of the `or` (simple word? or end delimiter?).

Comment: I get it what are You saying but what if strings ends in two ways one with `;` and other with this pattern `; or`. Then how we can modify the above expression to accommodate this change? I tried these versions -> `\([a-z]\).*?;|?or` or `\([a-z]\).*(?;|?or)` but non of them worked

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
s = """
SECTION 7.01. Events of Default. If any of the following events
("Events of Default") shall occur:
          (a) any Borrower shall fail to pay any principal of any Loan when and
     as the same shall become due and payable, whether at the due date thereof
     or at a date fixed for prepayment thereof or otherwise;
"""

r = r'(SECTION 7\.01\.[\s\w\.()"]*:)[\s]*(\(a\)[\s\w,]*;)'
mo = re.search(r, s)
print('Group 1: ' + mo.group(1))
print('Group 2: ' + mo.group(2))
```

If you wanted to make it generic, so you could grab the any number or section, you could try:

```
r = r'(SECTION [1-9]\.[0-9]{2}\.[\s\w\.()"]*:)[\s]*(\([a-z]\)[\s\w,]*;)'
```

Comment: But what about if i add one more point after `a`? try adding a point (b) and it should match to that point also in separate group.

Comment: if i write just `[\s]*(\([a-z]\)[\s\w,]*;)` then it captures all the points `(a)`, `(b)` but how to achieve the same thing with section in it?

Comment: You might want to try capturing a section and its points together with the regex, then use a string split to chop out all the points individually

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to help you learn, should you have to write another set of regex, I would recommend you check out the docs below:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

This is the "easy" introduction to python regex. Essentially, you're going to define a pattern, and use the above link as a reference to build your pattern as you need it. Then, call the pattern to apply it to whatever needs processing.